# json not displaying with dataType :'json'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

i'm tying to do an ajax get call 
i can successfully console.log the result without putting the datatype json in the ajax

```
    dataType: 'json',
```

when i console.log without it i get

```
{"id":"1","post_id":"748037498494861","post_title":"laptop","image1":"team217.jpg","price":"1234"}{"id":"2","post_id":"740811329642473","post_title":"remote control car","image1":"team522.jpg","price":"50"}{"id":"4","post_id":"316194613858174","post_title":"Ipad 3","image1":"team523.jpg","price":"400"}
```

however i cant display the json data 
if i put

```
     dataType: 'json',
```

my

```
      console.log
```

is empty
i dont understand where the problem is

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var username = $("#usernameinfo").text();

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",


    url: "<?= base_url()?>"+"account/listings/more_user_ads",
    data: {"username":username,"pid":"<?=$this->input->get('pid')?>"},
    success: function(res){
      console.log(res);   

}


});

});
```

php

```
 function more_user_ads(){
$post_id = $this->input->get('pid');

$username = $this->input->get('username');
$query = $this->get_where_custom('username', $username);
if($query->num_rows()>0){
    foreach($query->result() as $row){
        if($post_id != $row->post_id){
       $result = array(
           'id'=> $row->id,
           'post_id'=> $row->post_id,
           'post_title'=> $row->post_title,
           'image1'=> $row->image1,
           'price'=> $row->price,
           'price'=> $row->price,

       );

       $res = json_encode($result);

        echo $res;
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON, you don't echo `json_encode` calls in a loop

Comment: Run your string through: https://jsonlint.com/. It's not valid json so your ajax fails.

Comment: My guess is your PHP needs to run `header("Content-type: application/json");`; right now it's sending plain text that happens to be JSON. Also, you need to do `$res[] = $result;` inside the loop, then call `echo json_encode($res);` *once*, after the loop.

Comment: thanks for the info on putting the result as an array  it does console.log a different outcome however it still doesnt allow the datatype: 'json' thats with the hears changed

Comment: also retested the new json in the above link it still gives an error on line 7 ???

Comment: the result looks like it should be an array, but you are missing `[]` around the result, and `,` between the two items in the result ... because you're outputting JSON for each `$query->result` rather than one JSON for the whole result

Comment: It's a very good idea to include any error messages you are getting when you ask a question. In your case the full message text and clearly pointing out which line of code you show is line 7.

Answer (score 1):

Add each row to the $`result` array then `echo` the `json_encode` once.

```
public function more_user_ads()
{
    $post_id  = $this->input->get('pid');
    $username = $this->input->get('username');
    $query    = $this->get_where_custom('username', $username);

    $result = []; //so we have something if there are no rows
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            if($post_id != $row->post_id)
            {
                $result[] = array(
                    'id'         => $row->id,
                    'post_id'    => $row->post_id,
                    'post_title' => $row->post_title,
                    'image1'     => $row->image1,
                    'price'      => $row->price,
                    'price'      => $row->price,
                );
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Actually, you can shorten this a bit by using `$query->result_array();` because you won't have to convert an object to an array.

```
public function more_user_ads()
{
    $post_id  = $this->input->get('pid');
    $username = $this->input->get('username');
    $query    = $this->get_where_custom('username', $username);

    $result = []; //so we have something if there are no rows
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $rows = $query->result_array();
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            if($post_id != $row['post_id'])
            {
                $result[] = $row;
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```